# Typing the Ref Composition API Vue

Tags: forms, vue.js, vuetify.js, ref, vue-composition-api

how could I type correctly my Ref `firstName` as string? There are 2 errors underlined, in the template - `{{ firstName }}`, and in the script - `const firstName = ref('') as String`. I suppose it has to do with the typing, for the Ref I assume is working correctly.

```
<template>
  </div> -->
  <v-sheet >
      <v-form fast-fail @submit.prevent>
        <v-text-field
          label="First name"
        >{{ firstName }}</v-text-field>
      </v-form>
    </v-sheet>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue'
export default {
  setup() {
    const firstName = ref('') as String
  },
  }
</script>
```

Comment: `const firstName = ref<string>('')`

Comment: BTW I don't think that is your problem. You need to return the firstName from your script setup function so the template has access to it. add `return {firstName};` to the bottom of your `setup()` function. Alternatively, you could switch to the script setup syntax sugar, which is the recommended way to write your components. https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compilation from both comments

`<script>` version

```
<script lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue'
export default {
  setup() {
    const firstName = ref<string>('Alexander')
    return {firstName}
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  {{ firstName }}
</template>
```

`<script setup>` version

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue'
const firstName = ref<string>('Alexander')
</script>

<template>
  {{ firstName }}
</template>
```

[SFC Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#__SSR__eNp9j91qwzAMhV9F+CYbNMl9SAt9gT2Bb7JMyVziHySlGxi/++R1jLJB73yOjj4fZXNOqbvuaAYz8kwuCTDKnmCbwnq0Rtiakw3Op0gCGQgXKLBQ9NDoWmPDHAMLLI5YXiaPcKyZkYVcWE9PzXnDzym8ITXPNoz97Q8lqhD0aZsEVQHkfMcopWZ/5+ZgbgVaP6XuwjFo3Vy37M9AWw7w7VRPi1VtzbtI4qHveZnrkRfuIq29vjragziPHbJvXyl+MJKCrTncMXo1r0gtYe2P9Ij5J/qPW7F6VDHlC4wIgmk=)